# How to remove EOF's from pipes? Or: How to use tail -f with netcat?

Tags: tcp, websocket, pipe, chess, netcat

I am trying to pipe XBoard chess commands over TCP. I understand that `nc` will close a connection when it sees EOF.

### Example 1

```
$ nc -l 1301 | hd &
[1] 10241
$ echo -en "babab" | nc localhost 1301
00000000  62 61 62 61 62                                    |babab|
00000005
[1]+  Done                    nc -l 1301 | hd
$
```

That is my problem and I just think I need to find out how to make it so that the `nc -l` command above don't terminate. I have read that I could use `tail -f`, but that doesn't seem to work unless I use files or FIFO's. Now here is an explanation of a similar problem (I think) that caused me to search for a solution to this problem:

### Example 2

I want to run an XBoard Chess engine in the browser and communicate over WebSockets. I therefore launch XBoard like this:

```
./websockify 2023 -- xboard -fcp "nc -q -1 -k -l 2023"
```

It starts up and websockify seems to buffer the initial commands from XBoard. I now connect the browser like this:

```
ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:2023/", "base64");
ws.onclose = function(){console.log("close");};
ws.onmessage = function(evt){console.log(window.atob(evt.data));};
ws.onopen = function(){console.log("open");}
```

(executed in the console on one line)

It connects and I make the first move in XBoard as white, this is the output in the browser console:

```
open
xboard
protover 2
[2 second delay]
[other commands]
time 30000
otim 30000
b2b3
```

Everything is good. Now I make a move as black, from the browser: `ws.send(window.btoa("move b7b5\n"));`
Works too.

Now, when I go and make the third move of the game in XBoard, it doesn't work anymore. Immediately after mouseup this console output appears:

```
  1: 127.0.0.1: Target closed
xboard: Error writing to first chess program: Broken pipe
xboard: Error writing to first chess program: Broken pipe
xboard: Error writing to first chess program: Broken pipe
xboard: Error: first chess program (nc -q -1 -k -l 2023) exited unexpectedly
```

The GUI shows the same.

So my hypothesis is that an EOF is somehow sent from XBoard to netcat after the first move. This doesn't really make sense, cause how come didn't websockify report "target closed" earlier? And what made the first move so different from all the other commands XBoard sent?

Comment: Note that DOS and Windows will happily treat ^Z as an `EOF` character, but Unix-derived systems do not have an `EOF` character. (Typing `^D` at the _terminal_ asks the terminal to close a pipe, but that is a feature of the terminal being used.) The mechanism behind the scenes is that the pipe is actually closed.

Comment: @sarnold But how does the receiving netcat know when the EOF is, then? The terminal can't tell it, since it's not even receiving input from the terminal. I told netcat to listen for multiple connections (``-k``) and wait forever (``-q -1``).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes! I found a solution.

I changed the xboard "engine" command to `./runserver.sh` and wrote `runserver.sh` as (execute flag set):

```
#!/bin/sh
nc -q -1 -k -l 2023 | tee /dev/null
```

Everything works now!

Comment: Nice! That ought to win some kind of cleverness award.